# Implications of panic() with struct vs pointer?

Tags: go

What are the implications, if any, of calling `panic(x)` with a large struct, versus calling `panic(&x)` with a pointer to that struct instead?

Does the `interface{}` that you pass to panic get copied over each time the stack unwinds a level, or is there some other magic going on?

EDIT: An example of where this could be important is inside `http.Serve`, where it will recover from any panic and serve a suitable message. If I panic with a really large struct, this could have some performance impact as the stack frames unwind and cause undue load to my webserver.

Comment: _everything_ is by value, so the interface gets copied, not the value you put in it. Regardless, `panic` itself isn't cheap, and you probably should't be using it if performance is a real concern. Are you cure there's not a better way to do what you want?

Comment: Just handle every `error` as it comes (or return it to the caller) and you never have the need to `panic`.

Comment: This is a bit tongue in cheek, but does performance really matter when you are aborting your program?

Comment: Fair comments all; this was more for my curiosity than for any real world application. One application that does come to mind is an http.Handler, which recovers from any panic *per request*, and might have some performance impact there.

Comment: Just as long as you aren't trying to use `panic` as a pseudo `try` `catch`. Might throw a fit haha. It has some select use-cases as such, but should by no means become a try/catch replacement.

Comment: Why do you care about the performance of `panic`? Trying to prove that Go can even crash faster than nodejs?

Comment: Wow, my question seems to have upset some folks. Enough for at least 3 people to downvote it that it "doesn't show any research effort, is unclear or not useful". So much for my curiosity. I've edited to try clarify my reasons for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many times `panic`s are executed, on value or pointer argument, on the size of the `struct`, and so on. In Go, arguments are passed by value. Interface values are represented as a two-word pair giving a pointer to information about the type stored in the interface and a pointer to a copy of the associated data.

Use the Go testing package benchmark facilities. For example,

```
package main

import "testing"

var sink int

func panic(interface{}) {}

func BenchmarkPanicVal1K(b *testing.B) {
    var large struct{ big [1024]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        panic(large)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPanicPtr1K(b *testing.B) {
    var large struct{ big [1024]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        panic(&large)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPanicVal4K(b *testing.B) {
    var large struct{ big [4096]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        panic(large)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPanicPtr4K(b *testing.B) {
    var large struct{ big [4096]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        panic(&large)
    }
}

func BenchmarkIfaceVal1K(b *testing.B) {
    var iface interface{}
    var large struct{ big [1024]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        iface = large
    }
    _ = iface
}

func BenchmarkIfacePtr1K(b *testing.B) {
    var iface interface{}
    var large struct{ big [1024]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        iface = &large
    }
    _ = iface
}
func BenchmarkIfaceVal4K(b *testing.B) {
    var iface interface{}
    var large struct{ big [4096]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        iface = large
    }
    _ = iface
}

func BenchmarkIfacePtr4K(b *testing.B) {
    var iface interface{}
    var large struct{ big [4096]byte }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        iface = &large
    }
    _ = iface
}
```

Output:

```
$ gotest panic_test.go -bench=.

BenchmarkPanicVal1K-4      20000000      70.3 ns/op        0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkPanicPtr1K-4    2000000000       0.36 ns/op       0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkPanicVal4K-4       1000000    1483 ns/op       4096 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkPanicPtr4K-4    2000000000       0.36 ns/op       0 B/op    0 allocs/op


BenchmarkIfaceVal1K-4       5000000     378 ns/op       1024 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkIfacePtr1K-4    2000000000       0.36 ns/op       0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIfaceVal4K-4       1000000    1469 ns/op       4096 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkIfacePtr4K-4    2000000000       0.36 ns/op       0 B/op    0 allocs/op
```

References:

[Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Comment: I wonder why `BenchmarkPanicVal1K` doesn't alloc. Is there a bug in the code? Doesn't appear so, but it should also have 1024 B/op, no?

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: `B/op` and `allocs/op` are for heap allocations. By design, I benchmarked 1K and 4K allocations to illustrate stack versus heap allocation.

Comment: Is there some significance with 1024 bytes then that makes it allocate on the stack? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: Go gc is an optimizing compiler.

Comment: OK, I figured it was some sort of optimization wizardry. Thanks

Comment: So, you declare your own `panic` function at the start of this code, and I guess part of my original question was: is there some special behaviour that a regular panic has, or does it just get its parameters by value like everything else.

But this code was easy enough to adapt to add a "testPanic" function which does a panic + deferred recover, and benchmark that. And I get the same kind of results. So, thanks for this.